# How to make a button not clickable if another button is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons, when button 1 is clicked it will display an element, the same thing goes for button 2.
The problem is, if button 1 is clicked and you try to click button 2 I want it to display an error message that you need to close button 1, same thing goes for if button 2 is open and you click button 1.

**Button1**

```
    <div class="button" id="button1" onclick="function1()">
<p id="button1_text">Animation</p>
</div>

<script>
function function1(){
var e = document.getElementById("front_page_blur");
if(e.style.animationName !== "slide") {                             
e.setAttribute("style", "position:relative;");           
e.style.animationName = "slide"; 
e.style.animationDuration = "1s";
$("#button1_animation").fadeIn(1500);

}
else {                                                       
e.style.animationName = "back";
e.style.animationDuration = "1s";
$("#button1_animation").fadeOut(1000);
}}
</script>
```

**Button2**

```
<div class="button" id="button2" onclick="function2()">
<p id="button2_text">Eclipse</p>
</div>
<script>
function function2(){
var s = document.getElementById("front_page_blur");
if(s.style.animationName !== "slideDown") {
s.setAttribute("style", "position:relative;");
s.style.animationName = "slideDown";
s.style.animationDuration = "1s";
$("#button2_animation").fadeIn(1500);
}
else {
s.style.animationName = "slideDownBack";
s.style.animationDuration = "1s";
$("#button2_animation").fadeOut(1000);
}}
</script>
```

How and where can I call function1 in function 2 to make it possible and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bind this to click handler**

```
if ($('#button1_animation').is(':visible')) {
   alert('Close button 1');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do with jQuery and the function toggle, take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have more than 2 or 3 buttons, you may find the below approach more flexible.

```js
$('.my_btns').click(function() {
  $('#error').hide();
  if(($('.active-btn').length && !$(this).hasClass('active-btn'))){
    // a button has the class but it's not this one, so some other button is open
    $('#error').show();
  }
  else if($(this).hasClass('active-btn')){
    // this button has the class so it is open
    // close the stuff....
    // remove the class
    $(this).css("padding", "0px"); // just simulating animation here
    $(this).removeClass('active-btn');
  }
  else{
    // no buttons have the class so none are opne
    // open the stuff....
    // add the class
    $(this).css("padding", "20px");// just simulating animation here
    $(this).addClass('active-btn');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.button{
  background-color:#3095DC;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
#error{
  display:none;
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="error">Close the other button first</div>
<div class="button my_btns" id="button1">
  <p id="button1_text">Animation</p>
</div>
<div class="button my_btns" id="button2">
  <p id="button2_text">Eclipse</p>
</div>
```